CMake 3(.27(.7)) : check syntax/structure only
With CMake 3(.27(.7)), how to only check for syntax and structure without actually performing any of the commands ? I am doing a fairly complex code merge and want to be careful and step-by-step.

check for syntax and structure of what?

Of my CMakeLists file. I fear that during the merge some endifs() and generally some blocks were put in disorder.

so you will only merge without actually compiling and unittesting your program? cmake-lint exists https://cmake-format.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cmake-lint.html

I will compile later. I have more merging to do in the actual source code, for now I just want to check how the merging of the CMakeLists went, while all the changes are fresh in my head.
